# Time conversion issue in go language

Tags: go, time

I'm trying to understand the issue with time conversion in Go language. Here is code example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func unix2Str(ts int64) string {
    const layout = "20060102"
    t := time.Unix(ts, 0)
    return t.Format(layout)
}

func unixTime(ts string) int64 {
    const layout = "20060102"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, ts)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return 0
    }
    return t.Unix()
}
func main() {
    ts1 := "20110320"
    ts2 := "20110321"

    ut1 := unixTime(ts1)
    ut2 := unixTime(ts2)

    fmt.Println(ts1, ut1, unix2Str(ut1))
    fmt.Println(ts2, ut2, unix2Str(ut2))
}
```

It prints the following output:

```
20110320 1300579200 20110319
20110321 1300665600 20110320
```

But since I do the conversion from string format to Unix and reverse I would expect the same results for the date in string format. But it is not the case. In fact, the printed unix time `1300579200` is converted in python to original date I started with, e.g.

```
>>> time.strftime("%Y%m%d", time.gmtime(1300579200))
'20110320'
```

Is it a bug in Go code or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you certain this is the code you're running?: https://play.golang.org/p/wHQ3M5CHH53

Comment: ahh, cool, I'm running on OSX (
go version go1.9.4 darwin/amd64) and if I run on Linux it runs fine. So it seems like it is issue with Go on OSX only. Can someone try to run this snippet on OSX and verify if it is the case

Comment: yes, you're right, if I change code to use location it works as expected

Comment: Yes, it's safer to always specify locations. `time.Unix` sets `time.Local` -- maybe it shouldn't but probably not something that can be changed at this point. I think it should be at least specified in the docs.

Comment: @JimB: Beware of using the Go playground for package `time` code examples. The playground has special properties: "In the playground the time begins at 2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is because of the difference between your local time zone and UTC. `Parse` returned UTC time and `Unix` returned local time. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func unix2Str(ts int64) string {
    const layout = "20060102"
    t := time.Unix(ts, 0)
    fmt.Println(t)
    return t.Format(layout)
}

func unixTime(ts string) int64 {
    const layout = "20060102"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, ts)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return 0
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
    return t.Unix()
}

func main() {
    ts1 := "20110320"
    ts2 := "20110321"

    ut1 := unixTime(ts1)
    ut2 := unixTime(ts2)

    fmt.Println(ts1, ut1, unix2Str(ut1))
    fmt.Println(ts2, ut2, unix2Str(ut2))
}
```

Output:

```
2011-03-20 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2011-03-21 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
2011-03-19 20:00:00 -0400 EDT
20110320 1300579200 20110319
2011-03-20 20:00:00 -0400 EDT
20110321 1300665600 20110320
```

---

> [func Parse](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse)
>
> ```
> func Parse(layout, value string) (Time, error)
> ```
>
> Parse parses a formatted string and returns the time value it
>   represents. The layout defines the format by showing how the reference
>   time, defined to be
>
> ```
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
> ```
>
> would be interpreted if it were the value; it serves as an example of
>   the input format. The same interpretation will then be made to the
>   input string.
>
> In the absence of a time zone indicator, Parse returns a time in UTC.

---

> [func Unix](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix)
>
> ```
> func Unix(sec int64, nsec int64) Time
> ```
>
> Unix returns the local Time corresponding to the given Unix time, sec
>   seconds and nsec nanoseconds since January 1, 1970 UTC.

Comment: Since unix timestamps are UTC, shouldn't `time.Unix` use `time.UTC` rather than the local location?

Comment: @JimB: It seems to me that the code is working as expected. See the documentation. `Parse` returns UTC and `Unix` returns Local.

Comment: Yup, thanks, I read that a few times and missed "returns the local Time" every time.